# How to start compile SCSS to CSS on PhpStorm for example with File Watcher

Tags: phpstorm

I have start using SCSS for the frontend, and can setup it correctly with PhpStorm on the a MacBook Pro with Mojave installed.

First I install the npm:
[image: first i install the npm]

Then I setup the file watcher:
[image: then i setup the file watcher]

But it does not work. Something what I not seeing here?

Comment: Check `Arguments` field -- the syntax used by `node-sass` is different to what Ruby based compiler uses.

Comment: it has to be "can't setup"

Comment: do you have any Idea how it had to be?

Answer (score 1):

If you like the `.css` files to be generated in the same folder as original file, try the following settings:

[image]

Note the **Create output file from stdout** option - it has to be enabled, as `node-sass` writes CSS to stdout unless the `-o` option is passed.

If you like to place generated files in a separate folder, use the `-o` option:

[image]

Comment: what doesn't work? What does your watcher look like?